# User Connection

Tags: iphone, swift, network-programming, mobile-application

**My main question is how do developers allow users to connect to each other in applications?**

For instance when using the Omegle application a user is allowed to press a button and the application connects them automatically to another user.

I guess I am a bit confused on the whole process in general.  Thanks!

Comment: You can check [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) for chat support also.

Comment: it depends on the type of the connection, but basically a server in the cloud connects the clients together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party SDk's to implement this feature , you can use
 XMPP:-(Example link) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190
or PubNub :- https://www.pubnub.com/solutions/chat/ 
or QuickBlox:- http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS

And there are many other SDk's also which you can use

Thanks

Omkar